# Can you do a before create action on a rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a create action but I only want the create action to create IF 2 items in the form that is trying to be created are true. Is that possible to do a if statement before completing the create action or is that making my controller too fat?

I have a form that I want to submit to my db, but based on some of the questions in the form, I want the form to bring up another page (A payment page) BEFORE it puts the form info into the db. Only after the charge is successful will the controller put the info in the db if the charge goes thru.

So I want to know is it DRY or even possible to put logic that will preceed the create action in the controller?

--Additional Information--

So Im still trying to get this right... 
In my form controller I have

```
def intermediary
  if @model.who_pays == true
    @amount = @model.how_much_to_pay
    redirect_to charge_path, :notice => "Please make payment before proceeding"
  else
    redirect_to model_path #to create object
  end
end
```

and then in my actual form I had

```
Model.new
```

but i'm changing it to

```
<%= form_for [@model, url: [intermediary_path]] do |f| %>
```

is this logic correct?

Comment: Can you give some more detail?  Based on what you've written, though, it sounds like that's application logic which belongs in model or form object validations.

Comment: Just to check whether I'm understanding your desired behavior correctly: Submit Form -> Check Attrs `:x` and `:y` -> If Both Attrs True, Create Record || Elsif Either Attr False, Render Payment View -> Submit Payment Form -> Create Payment Record AND Create Original Record.  Without getting into *how* that happens, that is roughly what you want to happen — right?

Comment: Im sorry actually it is Submit Form -> Check Attrs :x -> If  Attrs X False, Create Record || Elsif Attr True ->Get payment Amount from Attrs: Y, Render Payment View showing Attrs Y as amount due -> Submit Payment Form -> Upon Sucessful charge ->  Create Original Record

Comment: The tricky part about that flow is you need to preserve some state (in this case, knowledge of the attributes submitted by the original form) while the user does another whole "round trip" to handle the payment (which could *itself* fail for any number of reasons).  So it's not the kind of thing you can comfortably handle just in the controller — you need to kick those original attributes into the database to preserve them across requests.  Consider creating an "original thing" database record with an `:is_paid` column set to `false`, then handling the payment flow separately.

Comment: I was thinking that but if I do that and the payment never were to go thru can I destroy that item from the database or keep it seperate? Or do I have to go thru all my logic and add if attr X  & attr Y != True then ignore

Comment: There are a few ways to handle that lingering "original thing" record.  You could keep it around in the DB indefinitely (hard to say whether this makes sense without knowing what that thing is).  Or you could have a cron job periodically (daily, weekly, etc.) remove all unpaid "original thing" records.  In either case, having a `:paid` scope on your `OriginalThing` model would make it easier to select only paid records if you have paid-specific things you want to do to "original thing" records elsewhere in your app.

Comment: What about using javascript? Can I make the attrs: X if selected bring up the charge in a modal and after paid it send a paid to the form and allow the form to be submitted? Otherwise I will have to do the cron job. Just thought there was a better way

Comment: I was keeping my feedback around the original question of "can this be done in the controller", but there are a lot of ways this can be done in Rails *before* I'd suggest reaching for Javascript.  Nothing against JS itself — it's just easier to keep a flow like this in the Rails "layer" (vs. starting to involve client-side logic & interactions).  The very first comment (re: using a model to handle this business logic) is the direction I'd suggest.  Hard to get deeper into it without knowing more about the existing moving parts of your Rails app.

Comment: Understood and appreciated! Thanks for the talk!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the extra form, this should be handled in your model with [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validation-helpers):

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @model = Model.new
   end

   def create
      @model = Model.new model_params
      @model.save
   end
end
```

In your model...

```
#app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   validate :true_questions, on: :create

   private

   def true_questions
      errors.add(:option1, "Must be true") unless option1
      errors.add(:option2, "Must be true") unless option2
   end   
end
```

---

*With* the form, you'll have several choices:

> 1. An "intermediary" action with sessions / cookies
> 2. JS / Ajax

As mentioned in the comments, this is a question of ["state"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science)) -- IE how you're able to keep the data integrity throughout the process.

You should check out how [stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails) handle this - they send the user to an authentication page (where they receive a token), are redirected back to "confirm" page, from which they're able to proceed.

-

**Intermediary**

If you have an intermediary action, you'll have to change your flow a little:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :controller do
   get :intermediary, on: :collection
end

#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   def intermediary
      # perform validations in the controller
      # set instance or session vars if necessary
      # render payment page
   end
   def create
      # returned from payment system - input into DB
   end
end
```

This would work quite well, although it means having custom routes and another action.

-

**Ajax**

A different approach would be to use either Ajax / JS.

This would be achieved by sending data to your app (probably to your "create" action) with certain switches defined. These would give you the ability to perform the required validations before invoking the payment view.

The payment view would be where the Ajax would come in:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("submit", "#____", function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: "controller",
      method: "POST",
      data: .......
      success: function(data){
         // show payment page
      }
   });
});

#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   def create
      if params[:x] 
          # perform validation
          # return payment form
      else
          # capture payment data
          # save to db
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: Ok thank you Rich. I am trying to implement this but to make sure I understand you. Is the intermediary action actually sending the form to another route BEFORE it goes to the final destination? So should my form not submit to the intermediary? Should my view show something like     ````<%= form_for [:interemdiary_path], :validate => true do |f| %>```` then on my charge controller it submit to the true form that was originally intended?

Comment: You'd need to use `form_for @object, url: [intermediary_path]` but yes that's what I had in mind :). Personally, I would try my hand at a stripe implementation -- it will help you see how they do it; their process is very similar

Comment: Can we speak about this in a private discussion. I am having a slight issue on how to set this up.

Comment: Sure, let me see how to do a private chat thing

Comment: I have looked at all the options you posted and I think the best solution is to allow the record to record but if it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93168/discussion-between-rich-peck-and-supremea).

Comment: is not paid for by the requesting user then it will show the receiving user a must pay page